# how to get value of button through jquery in formcollection with id of form collection?

Tags: jquery

i have formcollection and two buttons like

```
 <form id="frmSubmitTax" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="btnTaxSave" value="Save" /> 
 <input type="submit" id="btnTaxNext" value="Next" />
 </form>
```

i m submitting form  through jquery and i want to get value of button while form submitting
jquery code

```
    $('frmSubmitTax').live('submit', function (e) {
 get value of button that which button is submitted......
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$('frmSubmitTax').live('submit', function (e) {
   var id= $(e.target).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

Not tested.

Another Solution

Check the live working demo http://jsfiddle.net/fKppt/162/

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the last button being clicked and it will be the one that caused the submit.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cKHwA/1/)

```
var target = null;
$('#frmSubmitTax :input').click(function() {
    target = this;
});
$('#frmSubmitTax').submit(function() {
    alert(target.value);
});​
```

Edit for dynamcically generated contents using **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cKHwA/2/)**

```
var target = null;
$('#frmSubmitTax').on('click', ':input',function() {
    target = this;
});

$(document).on('submit', '#frmSubmitTax',function() {
    alert(target.value);
});​
```

Comment: Do you have another solution for this.. because it is worked only when my project loads first time.....

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your HTML. You should change

`<input type="submit" id="btnTaxNext"> value="Next" />`

to

`<input type="submit" id="btnTaxNext" value="Next" />`

For the jQuery part:

```
$('#frmSubmitTax').live('submit', function (e) {
 console.log($(this).find('#btnTaxSave').val(); //first value
 console.log($(this).find('#btnTaxNext').val(); //second value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('#frmSubmitTax').live('submit', function (e) {

     $(this).find('#btnTaxSave') // for accessing button inside form scope


  }
```